# sql developer daily table drop/creation task

Tags: sql, oracle, macros, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a daily task of updating 2 tables in my database...
one is based on report run from other source and I'm manually dropping the table and importing the table from excel to replace it.

then I need to run an SQL code which is performing calculations using refreshed data from 1st step and creating the table that is then being used for Tableau.

in a nutshell steps are:

1. `DROP TABLE table1 PURGE;`
2. manual insert of data from excel as table1,
3. DROP TABLE table_tableau PURGE;
4. CREATE TABLE table_tableau AS
   SQL calculations here;
5. create index for table_tableau
6. GRANT SELECT ON ... to grant access to the table..

my question is is there a way (If I store the file also under the same name in the same folder.) to have a stored sequence of tasks that SQL will perform? sort of like a one click Macro?

Comment: Use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, in a nutshell steps **should be**:

- Make sure to save Excel file as a CSV file (a *textual* file)

  - why? Because you'll later use it as an **external table**. You just read data from it, there's nothing special you should do; just name the CSV file with the same name you used while creating the external table
- The following steps should be done only once, *today*, and never again; in Oracle, we usually don't do *daily droppings & recreating* tables

  ```
  CREATE TABLE table1 (...) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (...);
  CREATE TABLE table_tableau (...);
  CREATE INDEX for table_tableau;
  GRANT SELECT ON table_tableau TO whomever_you_want;
  ```
- Daily task: no need to do anything with `table1`; as soon as you replace the CSV file, you'll see only new data. No *loading* data, nothing. Create a stored procedure which will do the rest of the job

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_daily AS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE table_tableau';
    INSERT INTO table_tableau SELECT ... calculations here FROM table1;
  END;
  ```
- Finally: if you can acquire the CSV file - automatically - at the same time (e.g. at 08:00 in the morning), you can use `DBMS_JOB` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER` to *schedule* the `P_DAILY` procedure to run at desired time of the day (e.g. 08:30).

  If you include `UTL_MAIL` call into `P_DAILY`, the procedure will inform you (or someone else) that the job has been done.

Which means: you'd just sit and wait, Oracle will do *everything* for you.